# How unnest h2 table's result

Tags: sql, h2

I have this field

```
 project_numbers text ARRAY
```

now in h2 want to select it

```
SELECT UNNEST(project_numbers) FROM PROJECTS
```

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UNNEST` in SQL is not a regular **function**, it is a collection derived **table**. You can use it in the `FROM` clause:

```sql
SELECT * FROM UNNEST((SELECT project_numbers FROM tableName WHERE someCondition));
```

Comment: it says not found function UNNEST

Comment: It was introduced in H2 1.4.198 Beta, older versions don't have it.